# Query to find before and after values of a given value

Tags: oracle

If we have table  Employees

```
EMP_ID  ENAME  SALARY  DEPT_ID
1        abc    1000    10
2        bca    1050    10
3        dsa    2000    20
4        zxc    3000    30
5        bnm    5000    30
6        rty    5050    30
```

I want to get the rank of the salary with before 2 values and after 2 values including the given rank
Like if I give rank 4 it should give ranks 2,3,4,5,6  details.
output should be

```
5        bnm    5000    30
4        zxc    3000    30
3        dsa    2000    20
3        dsa    2000    20
2        bca    1050    10
1        abc    1000    10
```

I have a query

```
WITH dept_count AS (
    SELECT
        e.*, 
        dense_rank() over( ORDER BY salary DESC) AS rk
    FROM employees e
)

SELECT
    *
FROM dept_count dc 
WHERE dc.rk BETWEEN (
    SELECT
        c.rk-2
    FROM dept_count c
    WHERE c.rk =4
)
AND (
   SELECT
       c.rk + 2
   FROM dept_count c
   WHERE c.rk = 4
```

)

but I need a query which can be simplified.
Could someone help me with this query?

Comment: What if , for example, there are 3 rows ranked `4`, two rows ranked `3` and 2 rows ranked `5`, which result do you want?

Comment: yes, even if we have  3 rows for rank 4 all those ranks need to be pulled

Comment: How do you decide which 5 rows you want in this case?

Comment: I need all the rows , there is no specific count for the rows just need to pull above 2 ranks and below 2 ranks  of the mentioned rank .. If I give rank 3 it need to fetch all the rows of 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 ,5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use `ROW_NUMBER()` along with a substitution parameter :

```
WITH dept_count AS (
    SELECT
        e.*, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY salary DESC) AS rk
    FROM employees e
)
SELECT *
  FROM dept_count
 WHERE rk BETWEEN &prm - 2 AND &prm + 2
```